# Eejcutar un script dentro de otro script

Tags: php, script

Estoy haciendo un modulo en php usando **phpmaker**, el problema que tengo es que al grabar el registro debo enviar un correo con 4 archivos adjuntos al paciente.

Para eso una libreria externa llamada **JasperPHP**, el problema radica en que al llamar a la función que me crea los PDF en el primer intento no se generan. Ya he revisado y me di cuenta que al parecer el script deja algo abierto y por eso no se crean a la primera ejecución. Cuando al final del script uso la sentencia `die();` estos si se crean pero mi programa se detiene y no continua mostrando la lista que debe mostrar al terminar de grabar el registro.

Existe alguna otra manera de finalizar la ejecución del programa que genera el PDF sin afectar los scripts siguientes?

Si uso `die();` se crean los archivos pero se detiene el programa (no envia el correo y no muestra la lista, queda la pagina de edición en blanco)

Si no uso `die();` el programa continua pero no se crean los archivos PDF, por ende no los adjunta.

Así llamo a la función:

```php
GeneraPDFConsulta($consulta,1);
```

Adunto el código de mi función.

```php
function GeneraPDFConsulta($consulta, $noshow)
{

    //Envia a imprimir los reportes relacionados a la Consulta Medica por medio de su Id de Consulta
    $path = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ;

    //Genera el PDF de la Receta
    $url = $path . "/hrmedic/JasperPHP/rptreceta.php?consulta=" . $consulta . "&noshow=" . $noshow;
    echo "<SCRIPT>receta=window.open('$url', '_blank');</SCRIPT>";
    echo "<SCRIPT>receta.close();</SCRIPT>";    

    //Genera el PDF del Registro de Atención
    $url = $path . "/hrmedic/JasperPHP/rptatencion.php?consulta=" . $consulta . "&noshow=" . $noshow;
    echo "<SCRIPT>atencion=window.open('$url', '_blank');</SCRIPT>";
    echo "<SCRIPT>atencion.close();</SCRIPT>";

    //Genera el PDF de la Orden de Imagenes
    $url = $path . "/hrmedic/JasperPHP/rptimagen.php?consulta=" . $consulta . "&noshow=" . $noshow; 
    echo "<SCRIPT>imagen=window.open('$url', '_blank');</SCRIPT>";
    echo "<SCRIPT>imagen.close();</SCRIPT>";

    //Genera el PDF de la Orden de Examenes
    $url = $path . "/hrmedic/JasperPHP/rptlaboratorio.php?consulta=" . $consulta . "&noshow=" . $noshow;
    echo "<SCRIPT>laboratorio = window.open('$url', '_blank');</SCRIPT>";
    echo "<SCRIPT>laboratorio.close();</SCRIPT>";

    //Genera el PDF del Certificado de Atención
    $url = $path . "/hrmedic/JasperPHP/rptcertificado.php?consulta=" . $consulta . "&noshow=" . $noshow;    
    echo "<SCRIPT>certificado=window.open('$url', '_blank');</SCRIPT>"; 
    echo "<SCRIPT>certificado.close();</SCRIPT>";

       die();
```

Comment: Seguramente el problema está en el envio de cabeceras header() por alguna parte, pues una vez se usan no puedes mandar nada nuevo a la pantalla porque no funciona.  Quizás deberías averiguar donde las ponen (o las pones tu) y dejar esa parte para el final del script, es decir, para cuando ya no debas mostrar nada más por pantalla.

Comment: Podira enviarte el codigo como para que veas lo que estoy realizando, no tengo experiencia en PHP talvez podrias ayudarme?

Comment: Lo siento, así no funciona el sitio.  Intenta reducir tu problema a un [example] y pulsa sobre el enlace [edit] para agregar el código que dices para que te podamos ayudar mejor.